# How can I multiply two matrices if I only store non-zero elements in a list<list<pair<int,double>>>?

Tags: c++, c++11

So I got my Data structures and algorithms project. I basically need to develop a class Matrix with following atributes:

1. list<list<pair<int,double>>>, (In which are only non-zero elements of a Matrix. Value of a certain element is stored as the second argument of a pair, and the first argument of a pair represents an actual column in which that element is located in the original Matrix)
2. vector< int> rows, (rows[i] - Represents an actual row for each list in a list of lists above, respectively)
3. Actual number of rows,
4. Actual number of columns.

In my project so far I have developed specific constructors, adding and substracting matrices etc. The only thing that I am not able to do is multiply two instances of a class Matrix, meaning I am not able to develop an operator* for class Matrix.

Explanation of the problem:

Assuming I have the following two instances of class Matrix:

Instance A:

```
        list<list<pair<int,double>>>: {{{10,5},{40,15}},{{50,25}},{{80,35}}}
        vector<int>: {2,10,70};
        actual number of rows: 100
        actual number of columns: 100
```

Instance B:

```
        list<list<pair<int,double>>>: {{{1,6},{2,5},{3,7}},{{3,4}},{{80,1}}}
        vector<int>: {1,2,33};
        actual number of rows: 100
        actual number of columns: 100
```

Obviously multiplication is defined for these matrices since the number of columns of matrix A is equal to the number of rows of matrix B.
I am having trouble with finding the correct algorithm for multiplying these matrices.
Can somebody write in short lines what could be one of the algorithms for multiplying these.

Comment: `Matrix& operator*=(const Matrix& rhs) { perform multiplication; return *this; }` and `Matrix operator*(const Matrix& lhs, const Matrix& rhs) { Matrix rv(lhs); rv *= rhs; return rv; }` would be a start.

Comment: Thank you for answering, performing multiplication is the toughest part here obviously, beacuse I cannot use anything else but the given atributes.

Comment: If you show your code (a [mcve]) someone might be able to help you with that.

Comment: _"I am not able to develop an operator*"_ it is not clear to me why you are unable to do this.  Are you saying that it produces the wrong answer?  Are you saying that you don't know the declaration syntax?  I'm guessing that you're stuck somewhere, but if my guess is right, you haven't mentioned _where_ you are stuck.

Comment: I think being given the class atributes anybody who actually knows how to solve this can answer with no problem.

Comment: whilst people could make guesses it'd be much easier to answer with a [mre]. What exactly are you stuck with? The algorithm? The syntax? A bug?

Comment: I am having trouble with finding out the proper algorithm to do this.

Comment: reference: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html

Comment: @SMAJKE you can always [edit] this question to clarify it.  As it's currently written, people are guessing what your real question/problem is.

Comment: I have no problem with understanding matrix multiplication in general nor implementing it with matrices in which I can also store the zero values. That's what makes this problem hard, non of the zero elements are stored..

Comment: The algorithm you are looking for is multiplying *sparse* matrices,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea consists in having convenient primitive to set/get the value at position (i, j) of a matrix, its number of rows and its number of column.

For sake of simplicity, I replaced in the following code your top list by a vector (it's more efficient as you have random access to the i-th value):

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Matrix {
    private:
        vector<list<pair<unsigned, double>>> data;
        unsigned m;
        unsigned n;
    public:
        Matrix(unsigned m, unsigned n):
            m(m),
            n(n),
            data(m)
        {}
        inline unsigned num_rows() const {
            return m;
        }
        inline unsigned num_columns() const {
            return n;
        }
        double get(unsigned i, unsigned j) const {
            for (pair<unsigned, double> p : data[i]) {
                if (p.first == j) return p.second;
            }
            return 0.0;
        }
        void set(unsigned i, unsigned j, double v) {
            for (pair<unsigned, double> p : data[i]) {
                if (p.first == j) {
                    p.second = v;
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (v) {
                data[i].push_back(make_pair(j, v));
            }
        }
};

Matrix operator * (const Matrix & a, const Matrix & b) {
    unsigned m = a.num_rows(),
             n = b.num_columns(),
             k_max = a.num_columns();
    assert (a.num_columns() == b.num_rows());
    Matrix c(m, n);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            double value = 0;
            for (unsigned k = 0; k < k_max; k++) {
                value += a.get(i, k) * b.get(k, j);
            }
            if (value) c.set(i, j, value);
        }
    }
    return c;
}

ostream & operator << (ostream & out, const Matrix & a) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < a.num_rows(); i++) {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < a.num_columns(); j++) {
            out << a.get(i, j) << "\t";
        }
        out << endl;
    }
    return out;
}

int main() {
    Matrix a(2, 3), b(3, 1);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < a.num_rows(); i++) {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < a.num_columns(); j++) {
            a.set(i, j, 10 * i + j);
        }
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < b.num_rows(); i++) {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < b.num_columns(); j++) {
            b.set(i, j, 10 * (i + 1));
        }
    }
    Matrix c = a * b;
    cout << "a:" << endl << a << endl
         << "b:" << endl << b << endl
         << "c:" << endl << c << endl
         ;
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
a:
0       1       2
10      11      12

b:
10
20
30

c:
80
680
```

Comment: Man you are a legend, as soon as I saw those get and set functions I got the idea of what the operator* implementation was going to be. Thank you so much <3